# Returning single row in an array when two rows are the same with the sum of the other column

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop

I have the result of a query stored in an array and some of the records have same values on one of the columns which is what it should be. Now for those records that have the same data in the first column, i want to sum up the values in the second column and return one row with the second column being the sum of the 2 rows. Here is an example.

RADSR   41

SOFTAC  10

SOFTAC  102

SOFTBC  44

SOFTCS  2

SOFTDW  8

```
if (sending != undefined){
        gist.push([value1, value2]);
    }   
        gist.sort();

for (var index = 0; index < gist.length; index++) {
                xmlMs += "<td>" + gist[index][0] + "</td>";         
                xmlMs += "<td>" + gist[index][1] + "</td>";
}
```

So my question is that i want to return just one row (SOFTAC) instead of rows 2 & 3 because they're the same and sum up their values in that row.

Answer (score 1):

This is surprisingly non-trivial to do without resorting to third-party libraries:

First, you can create a "map" of the unique keys and their accumulated values:

```
var gistMap = gist.reduce(function(result, current) {
    var key = current[0], value = current[1];
    result[c] = (result[c] || 0) + value;
    return result;
}, {} );
```

At this point, you can either iterate over the map (in whatever order it happens to be), or create a new sorted array in the original format:

```
var keys = Object.keys(gistMap).sort();
var newGist = keys.map(function(key) {
    return [key, gistMap[key]];
});
```